# TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str

Tags: python, dictionary

```
    import urllib2

    currency = 'EURO'
    req = urllib2.urlopen(' http://rate-exchange.appspot.com/currency?from=USD&to='+ currency +'') 
    result = req.read() 
    print p
    p = result["rate"]
    print int(p)
```

this what i got with `print p`
  result = {"to": "EURO", "rate": 0.76810814999999999, "from": "USD"}

but I have the error:

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str
```

Comment: Nope, not with that code you don't. The example you posted does *not* give an error. You probably did a `result = somestringvalue` somewhere in your code that you missed.

Comment: That code works fine for me in Python 2.7

Comment: What version of python?

Comment: @ValekHalfHeart: In Python 3 that code will throw a syntax error (because `print` is a function). In Python 2, the code Just Works. No point in asking for a version here.

Comment: Yep, confirming all that has been said: print int(p) prints 0, correct. Is that snippet all the code you got?

Comment: That code works fine for me in Python 2.7

I modified your code to print the output before casting to int (I called it test.py):

    `result = {"to": "EURO", "rate": 0.76810814999999999, "from": "USD"}
    p = result["rate"]
    print p
    print int(p)`

Output:

    `python test.py
    0.76810815
    0`

Comment: i have the 2.7 version

Comment: @imoum - Please reduce your original program to the smallest complete program that still demonstrates the error, and copy-paste *that* program into your question. See http://SSCCE.org for more info.

Answer (score 10):

The result of your `.read()` call isn't a dictionary, it's a string:

```
>>> import urllib2
>>> currency = "EURO"
>>> req = urllib2.urlopen('http://rate-exchange.appspot.com/currency?from=USD&to='+ currency +'')
>>> result = req.read()
>>> result
'{"to": "EURO", "rate": 0.76810814999999999, "from": "USD"}'
>>> type(result)
<type 'str'>
```

It looks like the result is a JSON-encoded dict, and so you can use something like

```
>>> import json, urllib2
>>> currency = "EURO"
>>> url = "http://rate-exchange.appspot.com/currency?from=USD&to=" + currency
>>> response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
>>> result = json.load(response)
>>> result
{u'to': u'EURO', u'rate': 0.76810815, u'from': u'USD'}
>>> type(result)
<type 'dict'>
>>> result["rate"]
0.76810815
>>> type(result["rate"])
<type 'float'>
```

[Note that I left your url construction alone, although I think there are better ways to handle adding parameters like `from` and `to`.  Also note that under the circumstances it doesn't make sense to convert the conversion rate into an `int`.]